# Right place for Sequel DB connection while working on Phusion Passenger with nginx

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, passenger, sequel

I have test app written on ruby, using Sinatra+Sequel.

config.ru:

```
require './main'

run Sinatra::Application
```

Example code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'
require 'sequel'

DB=Sequel.connect('oracle://test:test@test')

class Tarification < Sequel::Model(DB[:test_table]) 

end

get '/' do
  haml :index
end
```

Everything was all right until I started using Phusion Passenger in my test environment. Now I've got exception in nginx error.log:

> Sequel::DatabaseError - RuntimeError: The connection cannot be reused
>   in the forked process.

Is the right thing to place DB connection routine to rackup file config.ru or it's better to do it in a different way? If the first variant than how to make call to the connection correct from application code?

P.S.: I know that I can do `passenger_spawn_method conservative` and continue opening connection in app code, but it's not the way I'm looking for because of it's speed and resource usage issues.

Comment: In order to answer my own question I've found a bit of related info on [RubyForge](http://rubyforge.org/forum/message.php?msg_id=63321).
I had to place `DB.disconnect` at the very bottom of rackup file `config.ru`.
But I still think in depth of my mind that it's not overall correct approach. Any direction to sort out how Passenger will manage application would be appreciated.

Comment: Passenger doesn't offer a before fork hook that you can use, so calling DB.disconnect at the bottom of config.ru is the recommended approach if you are preloading your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is documented in [Appendix C.3](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_smart_spawning_gotcha_1_unintential_file_descriptor_sharing) of the Phusion Passenger manual. The usual method is to hook into the post-fork callback and re-establish the connection there.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't have ability to check it on Passenger and I don't know will it work, but it is more correct to connect in configure block:

```
configure do
  Sequel.connect(ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'sqlite://blog.db')
end
```

Example is form [Scanty](https://github.com/caleb/scanty/blob/master/main.rb) — another great Sinatra + Sequel application.